# IBM Filenet eform attachment

Tags: filenet-p8

Is there any way that the Filenet eForm can validate if there is an attachement attached ? That is ...eform will prompt for attachment if user did to attach any supporting documents.

Comment: Maybe some kind of custom validation?

Comment: Yes Heier ..i am like looking at something like the below ....

v_cre_sign = form.findCell("cre_sign").getValueAsString();
   
   if (v_cre_sign == "")
   {
      err_msg=err_msg + " #Please double click on your signature field to sign the Form" + CR;
      form_err="Y";
   }

any idea how it can be done if i will to check if there is any attachment in the eform ?